# ambiguous behavior of new line character

Tags: android, newline

I am uploading a large string to web-service. The string contains new line character which is written as "\n".
The data looks some thing like:

```
 05/06/2012 11:35:43 AM- DB exists, transferring data\n05/06/2012
 11:48:20 AM- loadUserSpinners, cursor.getCount()=2\n05/06/2012
 11:48:20 AM- Battery: 50%\n05/06/2012 11:48:20 AM- ITEM SELECTED: 0
```

the above data is stored in string `JsonArrObj`. To upload the data/string, i am using the following code:

```
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 360000; //6 minutes
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 420000; //7 minutes
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    JSONArray jsonParams = new JSONArray();
    Object[] params={IPAddress,Database,DbName,DbPassword,JsonArrObj};
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        jsonParams.put(params[i]);
    }

    JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
    jsonRequest.put("id", Id);
    jsonRequest.put("method", FunctionName);
    jsonRequest.put("params", jsonParams);
    JSONEntity entity = new JSONEntity(jsonRequest);
    entity.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");       
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);

            LogE("result line: "+line);
            String str=convertString(line);
            parseJson(str);
        }
        content.close();
    }
```

The string is uploaded successfully. The problem I am facing is: while string is being converted to `jsonParams`, the `"\n"` in the string data gets converted to `"\\n"` as a result, on the server side, it shows a small box in stead of new line.

When I open this string in NOTEPAD application, it displays small boxes. But when I open it in WORDPAD app, text is displayed on a new line. According to me, I might have entered in-correct "content-type" or encoding. Please suggest a solution for the same.

`JsonArrObj= URLEncoder.encode(JsonArrObj, "utf-8");`  gave error while uploading itself...

The data which is sent in the `jsonParams- jsonArrObj` finally looks like:

```
05\/06\/2012 04:05:52 PM- DB exists, transferring
data\\n05\/06\/2012 04:32:56 PM- loadUserSpinners,
cursor.getCount()\\u003d2\\n05\/06\/2012 04:32:56 PM- Battery:
50%\\n05\/06\/2012 04:32:56 PM- ITEM SELECTED: 0
```

Comment: have you tried putting an extra "\" in front of "\n"? that is "\\n" instead of "\n"?

Comment: @V.P.Verma, if i put a "\\n", i won't be able to display the text in the web-view. Also, the problem is to preserve the "\n" as is. The encoder is converting the "\n" to un-wanted "\\n"..

Comment: What if you send it as "\r\n"?

Comment: \n is used on Unix platforms and Wordpad seems to be able to understand it, but on Windows Notepad looks for \r\n to see at as new line character

Comment: @Anton it replaces the single box with 2 boxes (in notepad) and in wordpad, it shows 2 lines

Comment: @user370305 please go though it now. I have now written all of it.

Comment: Your values already contains '\n' character or it will added after you convert it into json?

Comment: Have you tried.. HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
request.setEntity(entity);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");?

Comment: \n is what i write in my code. when i create the JSON string it is converted to \\n

Comment: adding the header did not work...

Comment: Looks like a char escape issue. I would try Base64 encoding and decoding from the device and server.

Comment: @AshokFelix have tried that too. It converts the simple text into capital lettered words which don't make sense. Whatever I upload to the server, it writes the same thing and displays to me on the server side. Since I write meaning less words, it shows me meaning less words!

Comment: As of now, I have now asked my colleague who worked on the server code to manipulate the string as it comes to the server or while it is displaying the string from the server. If any one comes to know about alternate encoding technique in the future, please do write your answer here.

Comment: @Pallavi What I meant was => you encode it in the client and decode it on the server. So after encoding the original string, even if you write meaningless gibberish on the client device and send it to the server, once decoded, you should get the original string. I just need to know if this decoded string at the server still shows the \\n chars. If it does, then it's a client issue. If it doesn't, then its a server issue.

Comment: @Pallavi Got it now. The conversion at the client itself is failing. Now thats interesting. Have to test it out.

Comment: @AshokFelix right... have to handle it at server side itself.

Comment: @Pallavi what are you using on server side? PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the encoder escapes your newline characters. If you want to transport newline chars properly, you can encode the whole stream with base64. If your target os (for data to send) is Windows then you should use \r\n, if mac then \r if unix\linux then \n. After encoding data try to send the encoded and decode it on the other side. For base64 Mr. Google will convince you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why don't you use the Unicode values for \n as and any other character that is creating this problem
like this U+002FU+006E